# jQuery simplemodal closeHTML issue

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm having an issue where when initializing a modal window using the [jquery.simplemodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin.

With no `closeHTML` option, the modal window is formatted properly.

```
$.modal(html, {});
```

However, if I specify `closeHTML`, the modal window is formatted to fit in nearly a 10x10 pixel square with scrollbars.

```
$.modal(html, {
    closeHTML: '<a href="#close">Close</a>',
});
```

Has anyone run into this issue and have any idea for a fix?

Relevant specs are:

- Chrome8 on Ubuntu x86_64
- jQuery 1.4.4
- jquery.simplemodal 1.4.1

Comment: Not that you mention it, I think I've run into that before. I thought I had fixed it, but apparently not. I'll create an issue for it...if you happen to find a solution, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around this issue.  I just removed the text from the `<a class="modal-close">Close</a>` and went with `<a class="modal-close"></a>` and a css background image.  So really, if you want to use text in your `<a>`, like "x" or "close" this doesn't solve your problem, it just avoids the bug.  Maybe this helps Eric spot the issue.

- jQuery 1.4.4
- jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by adding a `closeClass` w/ some CSS:

**JS**:

```
$.modal(html, {
  closeHTML: '<a href="#">close</a>',
  closeClass: 'acme-modal-close'
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.acme-modal-close{
  display: inline;
  z-index: 3200;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```