# SimpleModal Hyperlink Click adds #

Tags: .net, razor

I having been having an issue, that appears to occur on the Web Server, even though no changes have been made to the code.

Clicking on "Schedule an Appointment" with Modal Open functions normal on Default.aspx:
http://www.davincispainting.com/

The issue occurs on the Virtual Directory Blog, however, usually many days after the site is uploaded.

This Modal works fine in the Blog for a period of time.
Then for no apparent reason, a Hashtag "#" is embedded into the URL which renders incapable the Modal Popup.

http://www.davincispainting.com/blog

I've cleared the Casche and checked on Chrome, Firefox, and IE.
Does anyone have a clue?

If you notice, this # is part of the markup.  If I take it out, the link doesnt function.

[image: Modal Issue]

The Blog utilizes Razor Pages:

```
<div id="contact-button">
    <div id='contact-form'>
        <a href="#" class="contact"></a>
    </div>
</div>


<div id='modal-contact-form' style='display: none'>
    <div class='contact-top'>
    </div>
    <div class='contact-content'>
        <h1 class='contact-title'>Send us a Message:</h1>
        <div class='contact-loading' style='display: none'>
        </div>
        <div class='contact-message' style='display: none'>
        </div>
        <form action='Contact.aspx' style='display: none'>
            <label for='contact-name'>
                *Name:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-name' class='contact-input' name='name'  tabindex='1001' />
            <label for='contact-email'>
                *Email:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-email' class='contact-input' name='email' tabindex='1002' />
            <label for='contact-subject'>
                Subject:</label>
            <input type='text' id='contact-subject' class='contact-input' name='subject' value='' tabindex='1003' />
            <label for='contact-message'>
                *Message:</label>
            <textarea id='contact-message' class='contact-input' name='message' cols='40' rows='4' tabindex='1004'></textarea>
            <br />
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <input type='checkbox' id='contact-cc' name='cc' value='1' tabindex='1005' />
            <span class='contact-cc'>Send me a copy</span>

            <br style="clear:both; line-height:0px;" />
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type='submit' class='contact-send contact-button' tabindex='1006'>
                Send</button>
            <button type='submit' class='contact-cancel contact-button simplemodal-close' tabindex='1007'>
            Cancel</button>
            <br />
            <input type="hidden" id="tokenValue" name="tokenValue" value="<%= new MailService().GetToken(0) %>" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class='contact-bottom'><a href='http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/'>Powered by SimpleModal</a></div>
</div>

/*
* SimpleModal Contact Form
* http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/
* http://code.google.com/p/simplemodal/
*
* Copyright (c) 2010 Eric Martin - http://ericmmartin.com
*
* Licensed under the MIT license:
*   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
*
* Revision: $Id: contact.js 254 2010-07-23 05:14:44Z emartin24 $
*/

jQuery(function ($) {
var contact = {
    message: null,
    init: function () {
        $('#contact-form input.contact, a.contact').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // create a modal dialog with the data
            $('#modal-contact-form').modal({
                closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                maxHeight: 390,
                maxWidth: 62,
                minHeight: 62,
                minWidth: 62,
                position: [132, 513],
                overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                containerId: 'contact-container',
                onOpen: contact.open,
                onShow: contact.show,
                onClose: contact.close
            });
        });
    },
    open: function (dialog) {
        // add padding to the buttons in firefox/mozilla
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-button').css({
                'padding-bottom': '2px'
            });
        }
        // input field font size
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('#contact-container .contact-input').css({
                'font-size': '.9em'
            });
        }

        // dynamically determine height
        var h = 280;
        if ($('#contact-subject').length) {
            h += 26;
        }
        if ($('#contact-cc').length) {
            h += 22;
        }

        var title = $('#contact-container .contact-title').html();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Loading...');
        dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function () {
            dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function () {
                dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function () {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                        height: h
                    }, function () {
                        $("#contact-form-container").css("display", "inline"); 
                        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html(title);
                        $('#contact-container form').fadeIn(200, function () {
                            $('#contact-container #contact-name').focus();

                            $('#contact-container .contact-cc').click(function () {
                                var cc = $('#contact-container #contact-cc');
                                cc.is(':checked') ? cc.attr('checked', '') : cc.attr('checked', 'checked');
                            });

                            // fix png's for IE 6
                            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 7) {
                                $('#contact-container .contact-button').each(function () {
                                    if ($(this).css('backgroundImage').match(/^url[("']+(.*\.png)[)"']+$/i)) {
                                        var src = RegExp.$1;
                                        $(this).css({
                                            backgroundImage: 'none',
                                            filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="' + src + '", sizingMethod="crop")'
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    show: function (dialog) {
        $('#contact-container .contact-send').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $('#contact-container form');

            // validate form
            if (contact.validate()) {
                var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message');
                msg.fadeOut(function () {
                    msg.removeClass('contact-error').empty();
                });
                $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Sending...');
                $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);

                $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
                    height: '80px'
                }, function () {

                    var uname = $('#contact-container #contact-name').val();
                    var email = $('#contact-container #contact-email').val();
                    var cntx = $('#contact-container #contact-message').val();

                    var docc = "false";
                    if ($('#contact-container #contact-cc').is(':checked')) {
                        docc = "true";
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "blog/api/Blogs.asmx/SendMail",
                      data: "{'uname':'" + uname + "', 'email':'" + email + "','cntx':'" + cntx + "','docc':'" + docc + "'}",
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json",
                      success: function (msg) {
                         //contact.close(dialog);
                         $('#contact-container .contact-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                            $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Thank you!');
                            msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                contact.close(dialog);
                            }, 1500);
                        });
                      }
                   });

                    contact.close(dialog);
                });
            }
            else {
                if ($('#contact-container .contact-message:visible').length > 0) {
                    var msg = $('#contact-container .contact-message div');
                    msg.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        msg.empty();
                        contact.showError();
                        msg.fadeIn(200);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#contact-container .contact-message').animate({
                        height: '30px'
                    }, contact.showError);
                }

            }
        });
    },
    close: function (dialog) {
        $("#contact-form-container").css("display", "none"); 
        $('#contact-container .contact-message').fadeOut();
        $('#contact-container .contact-title').html('Goodbye...');
        $('#contact-container form').fadeOut(200);
        $('#contact-container .contact-content').animate({
            height: 40
        }, function () {
            dialog.data.fadeOut(200, function () {
                dialog.container.fadeOut(200, function () {
                    dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    },
    validate: function () {
        contact.message = '';
        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-name').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Name is required. ';
        }

        var email = $('#contact-container #contact-email').val();
        if (!email) {
            contact.message += 'Email is required. ';
        }
        else {
            if (!contact.validateEmail(email)) {
                contact.message += 'Email is invalid. ';
            }
        }

        if (!$('#contact-container #contact-message').val()) {
            contact.message += 'Message is required.';
        }

        if (contact.message.length > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    },
    validateEmail: function (email) {
        var at = email.lastIndexOf("@");

        // Make sure the at (@) sybmol exists and  
        // it is not the first or last character
        if (at < 1 || (at + 1) === email.length)
            return false;

        // Make sure there aren't multiple periods together
        if (/(\.{2,})/.test(email))
            return false;

        // Break up the local and domain portions
        var local = email.substring(0, at);
        var domain = email.substring(at + 1);

        // Check lengths
        if (local.length < 1 || local.length > 64 || domain.length < 4 || domain.length > 255)
            return false;

        // Make sure local and domain don't start with or end with a period
        if (/(^\.|\.$)/.test(local) || /(^\.|\.$)/.test(domain))
            return false;

        // Check for quoted-string addresses
        // Since almost anything is allowed in a quoted-string address,
        // we're just going to let them go through
        if (!/^"(.+)"$/.test(local)) {
            // It's a dot-string address...check for valid characters
            if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9!#$%*\/?|^{}`~&'+=_\.]*$/.test(local))
                return false;
        }

        // Make sure domain contains only valid characters and at least one period
        if (!/^[-a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$/.test(domain) || domain.indexOf(".") === -1)
            return false;

        return true;
    },
    showError: function () {
        $('#contact-container .contact-message')
            .html($('<div class="contact-error"></div>').append(contact.message))
            .fadeIn(200);
    }
};

contact.init();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The Diagnosis***

When I open the blog with Chrome dev tools I notice that there are several errors that occur during page load, I believe this is your issue.  The `href="#"` doesn't have anything to do with the problem, and it should work with or without it since you are using jQuery events to trigger the modal.

***The Fix***

There seems to be syntax errors in your [/blog/Scripts/Header/js](http://www.davincispainting.com/blog/Scripts/Header/js) file.  It looks like you have an already minified version of jQuery in this file that contains a syntax error.  You are currently trying to use version ~1.5. Try replacing line 39 with a [valid copy of jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js).

If that doesn't work, you could try loading jQuery from a CDN before any other scripts that depend on it.

Hope that helps,
-Joe

Comment: I will have to look into that latest jQuery.  I'm not sure if a previous mod was made to the existing jQuery to accommodate the Modal.  I will download latest and test. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that you need the latest, but the version on the site currently has a syntax error.  The link I provided is a valid copy of 1.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try solution from this post: [jQuery simplemodal closeHTML issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558109/jquery-simplemodal-closehtml-issue)

Also as possible solution try like this:

```
<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close' onclick='return false;'>x</a>
```

**Edit**

I guess answer is much easier. There is no script which handles clicks. You said there should be some `contact.js` script. But there is no such script in my loadings:

[image]

Comment: You got it right, the main point is to use `onclick='return false;'`. It's old well known trick to prevent navigation.

Comment: when I added onclick='return false:' the Modal wouldn't pop-up.   Also changing within the js had no effect.

Comment: What is strange is that this works fine on the homepage.  The same code exists in the blog, which is a virtual directory.

Comment: <a href="#" class="contact" onclick='return false;'></a>   within the site.cshtml markup, causes the Modal to not fire.

Comment: As for http://www.davincispainting.com/blog you don't have any event listener for this button, beacause contact.js is not loaded here. So there is no chance you will get modal dialog :) You didn't include it :)

Comment: its called 33-contact.js

Comment: Anyway, this modal worked fine previously on http://www.davincispainting.com/blog  This problem occurs after a period of time on the server.

Comment: There is no such script as well, see console log and network statistics.

Comment: blog/scripts/33-contact.js  its there.  Anyway thank you for trying.

Comment: You are welcom, but I believe there is no such script. See pic in my updated answer.

Comment: Tony, Im loooking at the script- it exists.  I dont know why it doesnt show up in the Console.  All of the scripts that exist in the parent application, also exist in the blog which is a virtual application.  These scripts are prefixed with a number, such as 33-conact.js

Comment: the reason why you could not see 33-contact.js is because Site uses optimization to combine/mifiy scripts, therefore everything combined into Header/js

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to remove # then please remove it from href od <a> tag. Just because
of that you are getting error.

 $('#modal-contact-form').modal({
            closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
            maxHeight: 390,
            maxWidth: 62,
            minHeight: 62,
            minWidth: 62,
            position: [132, 513],
            overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
            containerId: 'contact-container',
            onOpen: contact.open,
            onShow: contact.show,
            onClose: contact.close
        });
```

i guess just because of the you are getting #. Remove it or use another link

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. That href has to do with the "close" portion of the Modal. What would this href=  be replaced with?

Comment: I tried removing and modified to only href='' which had no effect. The same exact javascript and href exists in the "close" portion of the parent application. And this has never had any problem. It's always with the blog.